# Ultracontractive semigroup generated by the fractional Laplacian

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, functional-inequalities

Let $A=-(-\Delta)^s$  with domain $D(A)=$ {$\phi\in\mathbb{H}_{0}^{s}(\Omega),(-\Delta)^s\phi\in  L^2(\Omega)$ }. $(-\Delta)^s$ is the fractional Laplacian of order $s\in(0,1)$.
We know that $A$ generates a strongly continuous semigroup {$S_A(t)$},  [see for instance](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.13312.pdf)  .

There is also a know result about the ultracontrativity of $A$. Namely, for any $\phi\in L^p(\Omega)$ and $1\leq p\leq q\leq +\infty$, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\lVert S_A(t)\phi \rVert_q\leq C t^{-\frac{N}{2s}(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q})}\lVert\phi\rVert_p$,

where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p = \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)}$.

I think the proof of the this estimate follows from the fact that  $A$ is a non-negative self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\Omega)$ with compact resolvent and that the semigroup ${S_A(t)}_{t\geq 0}$ is submarkovian. Would you please help me to find a reference that proves the ultracontractivity whether in the case of fractional Laplacian or in general case (for self-adjoint operators with Dirichlet condition). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You might check out the lecture notes "Heat Kernels" by W. Arendt. There is at least an entire chapter devoted to ultracontractivity.

Comment: The reference you provided me is useful and very interesting. Thank you very much.

Comment: How is it possible to conclude that $A$ generates a semigroup? Which Theorem was used? I have been trying this for a long time without success.